# Wheel of fortune loop simple

Tags: java, game-engine

I am trying to write a program for the game wheel of fortune, and i want it to just take in the user input for the word the would like to start the game with then make guesses after that. So far i have this.

```
String enterPhrase = (" Enter a phrase : ");    
    String guess = "";
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean notDone = true;
    while (notDone)
    {
        notDone = false;
        for(char guessLetter : enterPhrase.toCharArray()){

            if(guess.indexOf(guessLetter) == -1){
                System.out.println('*');
                notDone = true;

            } else {

                    System.out.println(guessLetter);
                    }
            }
                if( ! notDone) {break;}
                    System.out.println("Guess a letter: ");
                    String letter1 = input.next();
                    guess += letter1;



    }
    System.out.println("Hooray! It took you   guesses" );
  }
}
```

and it prints out this:

```
Guess a letter: 
d 
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
```

If i could get some help on how to make the dashes print horizontally. and have the input on each letter they guess if right and at the end of the program count how many times it took for them to complete the word.

Comment: Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` prints a string to the console and concatenates an endline to the string.

If you want to print the dashes horizontally, then you will be needing to use `System.out.print()` - which does not concatenate the endlines. This should be used when you're printing the individual letters of the guess (but obviously not when you're printing "Guess a letter:").

To calculate how many guesses it requires the user to get the whole string correct, simply store another variable, `int count`, initialized to 0. Every time they guess, increment this counter by 1.

Comment: i added the: int count `code` to the: if( ! notDone) {break;} `code`  and it puts one letter into the dash how do i get it to put the other letters it guesses when it runs again into the other dash while keeping the first one there

Comment: There are many ways to do it. How I would do it is remember the characters guessed in an array or a string. That way you're not over-writing the previous guesses, but rather adding to them. This is probably done easiest with string concatenation.